# How does current limiting work for the UC3825B?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, current-limiting

ILIM (pin 9) on the UC3825B is confusing to me. I know the current limit threshold voltage (typ. 1 V) and the overcurrent threshold voltage (typ. 1.2 V) [from the datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uc3825b.pdf?ts=1660761042782), but I don't know how that information is useful, or how to hook up this pin.

In the examples I've seen (specifically [this application note](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slua053/slua053.pdf?ts=1660689841713) on pg. 9) it seems there is a resistor (R3) hooked up to the ILIM pin right after the sense resistor(s?) R5-R8 (correct me if I'm wrong). They mention R3 and C8 are a RC network to suppress leading edge from mosfet turn-on.

1. How do you use the current limiting feature on this chip?
2. How did they calculate the RC network and why does this ILIM connection work?

I'd greatly appreciate some help, and as always let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Current sense is discussed on p. 3-96 (3) of the appnote ("Sense Resistor R (s)"). I agree the application information is brief, especially lacking in the datasheet. Mechanism appears similar to UC3842 family, if that's any help: they are well documented in comparison.

Comment: @TimWilliams Could you provide a link to these documents? I cannot find them from a google search. I do understand the sense resistor part fairly well regardless of the fact that they never use the sense resistor value mentioned in the application note. I'm only really confused about the ILIM portion.

Comment: Sure, https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slua143/slua143.pdf https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uc3842a.pdf The RC network to ILIM reduces leading-edge triggering, evidently they felt some was necessary in addition to the internal blanking feature.

Comment: @TimWilliams So basically you just connect the pin to the sense resistor (disregarding the RC network) and whatever voltage is going through it will be fine for the pin (since I already have the sense resistor calculated)? I'm sure you have to add at least one resistor right?

Comment: It can be direct, yes. There are also reasons you might want an R or RC, or other networks.

Comment: That extra \$RC\$ network is there to filter out any spurious pulses happening at turn-on. These spikes can wrongly trip the current sense comparator and stop operations erratically. See my answer on SE [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/585767/what-does-leading-edge-blanking-do-exactly). These extra elements should be located very closely to the control IC.